# How to enable explorer tab and add authorization prefix in graphiql playground?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql, graphiql

How to add (ex. "Authorization" : null ) prefix in graphiql playground

How to enable explorer tab to get available query and mutations

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxRNJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a `header` to request in Graphiql and there is no embedded `Explorer Tab` where you can see available query and mutations.
I recommend [`Apollo Server`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/) as a GraphQL UI where you can add headers to your requests and see available queries and mutations.